# Why is my matrix multiplication algorithm faster with a 2D C-style array than with a 1D std::array?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

I have been messing around with writing and optimising linear algebra stuff recently, just for educational purposes, and tried writing some code to see the difference between the different ways to store matrices.
As far as I know, there should be next to no difference in the runtime when using std::array and a C-style array, and I can't see any obvious differences between the time complexity of mult1 and mult2 in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
void setRandomValues(std::array<float, 10000>& arr1D) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    for (auto& element : arr1D) {
        element = static_cast<float>(dis(gen));
    }
}
void setRandomValues(float(&array)[100][100]) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
            array[i][j] = static_cast<float>(dis(gen));
        }
    }
}
void mult1(array<float, 10000>& mat1, array<float, 10000>& mat2, array<float, 10000>& mat3)
{
    int rowsize = 100;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < 100; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < 100; col++)
        {
            float sum = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            {
                int index1 = (row * rowsize) + k;
                int index2 = (k * rowsize) + col;
                sum += mat1[index1] * mat2[index2];
            }
            int index3 = (row * rowsize) + col;
            mat3[index3] = sum;
        }
    }
}
void mult2(float(&mat1)[100][100], float(&mat2)[100][100], float(&mat3)[100][100])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            float sum = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            {
                sum += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][x];
            }
            mat3[i][x] = sum;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    float mat1[100][100];
    float mat2[100][100];
    float mat3[100][100];
    std::array < float, 10000> mat4;
    std::array < float, 10000> mat5;
    std::array < float, 10000> mat6;
    setRandomValues(mat1);
    setRandomValues(mat2);
    setRandomValues(mat4);
    setRandomValues(mat5);

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        mult1(mat4, mat5, mat6);
    }

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);

    std::cout << "Using std::array in row major order " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        mult2(mat1, mat2, mat3);
    }

    stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);

    std::cout << "Using C style nested array " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

So why is it returning:

```
Using std::array in row-major order 711461
Using C style nested array 53742
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Hate such questions that miss #include and require to modify the posted code for getting it runnable.

Comment: After I fill in the includes, which I should not have to do, I get `error: 'setRandomValues' was not declared in this scope` Are you compiling with optimizations on? What happens if you reverse the order of the tests?

Comment: Can't replicate with the enabled optimizations. You likely did not enabled optimizations - unfortunately it happens very usually in questions on SO. https://godbolt.org/z/ca9d41saE

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry I committed quite a lot of code for brevity which was a mistake (now editing to include all of it). This is with max optimisations preferring speed enabled in Visual Studio 2022. Reversing the order of the tests makes no difference.

Comment: When you signed up on SO you should have taken the tour [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If I were to guess, without optimisations compiler performs all the index calculations you set it to do. They can be simplified, and that's what I guess happens when optimisations are enabled.

Comment: In general, a question about performance that doesn't include the compiler, compiler version, and build options (particularly those related to optimization) used cannot be adequately answered.

Comment: The performance numbers I got: `Using std::array in row major order 63868` and `Using C style nested array 63874`.  Using `/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -O3 Baguettio.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

> Have I missed something obvious?

Although I don't think this should explain such a large difference, you definitely missed one obvious thing: using `int` for the indices is bad.

For example, MSVC may (depending on how you compile the code) produce something like this:

```
$LL10@mult1:
        imul    eax, r8d, 100                     ; 00000064H
        add     eax, r9d
        movsxd  rdx, eax
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR [r10+r8]
        movsxd  rcx, eax
        inc     r8
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r11+rdx*4]
        mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbx+rcx*4]
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        cmp     r8, 100                             ; 00000064H
        jb      SHORT $LL10@mult1
```

The `movsxd` that performs the sign extension is not the worst thing here. The worst thing here is that the code has this form at all. With `size_t` indices (which you almost always should be using anyway), MSVC removes almost all of the index arithmetic *and* unrolls the loop:

```
$LL10@mult1:
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rcx-400]
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+4]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx-800]
        mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax]
        addss   xmm0, xmm2
        movaps  xmm2, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rcx+400]
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+12]
        addss   xmm2, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+8]
        mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm2, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx+800]
        mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+16]
        addss   xmm2, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rcx+1200]
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+20]
        addss   xmm2, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx+1600]
        mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+24]
        addss   xmm2, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rcx+2000]
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+28]
        addss   xmm2, xmm0
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+32]
        mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx+2400]
        addss   xmm2, xmm1
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+36]
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rcx+2800]
        add     rax, 40                             ; 00000028H
        add     rcx, 4000               ; 00000fa0H
        addss   xmm2, xmm0
        addss   xmm2, xmm1
        sub     r8, 1
        jne     $LL10@mult1
```

Though sadly there was no auto-vectorization. This is all still scalar code, just unrolled and with less overhead.

Comment: Also it appears to be calculating `(row * rowsize)` once per `k` instead of once per row https://godbolt.org/z/jbac9KK6f

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/q/XLMABbs2OdwLbKofP1oRwz8VFas clang compiles everything to the same performance though

Comment: @MooingDuck yea going by the assembly code there, Clang ignored that the indices were 32-bit and signed. Fair enough since overflow would be UB, but MSVC tends to be more conservative with that sort of thing